# Changing URL before onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

<a href="#/new-page" onclick="MyFunction()">Open Page</a>

Its current working is that onclick works before href because of which "MyFunction()" executes before URL is changed. I want URL to be changed first with href and then execute onclick.

Is there any methods available by which I can achieve this and I don't want to use "location.href" or any other dynamic URL changing method

Comment: can you please add a fiddle to demonstrate the problem you are facing ?

Comment: and I'm curious, why would you want to change the `href` on click even when the pahe is going to get navigated to a different page ?

Comment: Do you want to trigger javascript, on the new page after a redirect?

Comment: actually I dont wish to redirect to new page i want to change URL only

Comment: @Harsh you want to change the url in the href or the url in the url bar ?

Comment: @mrid I want to change URL in URL bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **history.js**:

```js
// this should be the Ajax Method.
// and load the url content
var setCurrentPage = function(url) {
    $('h2 span').html(url || "/");
    $("#menu-nav a[href='" + url + "']").fadeTo(500, 0.3);
};

$('#menu-nav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr('href'),
        targetTitle = $(this).attr('title');
    
    $("#menu-nav a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']").fadeTo(500, 1.0);
    
    window.history.pushState({url: "" + targetUrl + ""}, targetTitle, targetUrl);
    setCurrentPage(targetUrl);
});

window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    $("#menu-nav a").fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
    setCurrentPage(e.state ? e.state.url : null);
};
```

```css
body {margin:10px}
h1 {font-size:20px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h2>Current Page: <span>/</span></h2>
    <ul id="menu-nav">
        <li><a href="/page-1/" title="Pagina 1">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page-2/" title="Pagina 2">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page-3/" title="Pagina 3">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**UPDATE 1**:

Try using this

```
<a onclick="event.stopPropagation();if(this.href==undefined || this.href==''){fnMyCustomFunction();return;}else{window.location=this.href;}">This will call the function</a>
```

It is first checking if an `href` exists, if yes => it wont call the function, but navigate to the href location

DEMO: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrid/4pqft6f4/3/)

Comment: Since SO doesn't allow us to use this in the snippet, you can click on any page and see the link in the error message: .....something like `https://stacksnippets.net/page-3/`

Comment: if an "onclick" event is added to these links like "<a href="/page-1/" title="Pagina 1" onclick="fnMyCustomFunction()">Page 1</a>" then it first take me to "fnMyCustomFunction()" then any other operation is done

Comment: I have to prioritise href over onclick

Comment: This works fine for me but I still have to write logic on click event and have to assign URL dynamically, Is there any other way by which we don't have to write conditional logic or assigning URL with .href()

Comment: @Harsh not that I know of...I think you will have to handle that in the logic itself